# MySQL SELECT query with a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble making a SELECT/WHERE query using a many to many relationship type. A user inputs ingredients, and I want to find which recipes use *all* the ingredients provided among the other ingredients (if any). (Think: use up the last ingredients I have in my fridge)

My DB is currently designed like this:
[image: database structure]
`recipes_ingredients` looks like this
[image: recipes ingredients]

For example, if I give,`id_ingredient IN (22, 23)` i want the recipe #16497 only, not #16631 (since it only has 22 and not 23).

I've come up with something that does the opposite of what I described

```
SELECT DISTINCT recipes.*
FROM recipes_ingredients
JOIN recipes ON recipes_ingredients.id_recipe = recipes.id
WHERE id_ingredient IN ( 96, 13196 )
```

Comment: your question is not clear .. please update yoru question add  a proper data sample , the actual result and your expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get recipes which should have these both ingredients(not single ingredient) then you can use aggregation with some filter

```
SELECT  r.*
FROM recipes_ingredients i
JOIN recipes r ON i.id_recipe = r.id
WHERE i.id_ingredient IN ( 96, 13196 )
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.id_ingredient ) = 2
```

OR

```
SELECT  r.*
FROM recipes_ingredients i
JOIN recipes r ON i.id_recipe = r.id
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING SUM(i.id_ingredient = 96)
AND SUM(i.id_ingredient = 13196)
```

Comment: I like the first solution since it keeps the ingredients values together.

Comment: Yup, this does exactly what i wanted! I was close to the solution but didn't know what to put in the HAVING clause. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need recipes that contains all ingredients you have on the input then you may use `JOIN`

```
 SELECT recipes.* FROM recipes 
 JOIN recipes_ingredients r1 ON recipes.id = r1.id_recipe AND r1.id_ingredient = 96
 JOIN recipes_ingredients r2 ON recipes.id = r2.id_recipe AND r2.id_ingredient = 13192
```

Unfortunately there is no intersect operator in mysql which would be more simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) matches, id_recipe FROM `recipes_ingredients`
WHERE `id_ingredient` in ('23',...)
Group By `id_recipe`
WHERE matches = (
    SELECT count(*) FROM ingredients where id in ('23',...)
);
```

This provides the count of matching ingredients per recipe, then compares counts to the exact number of parameters passed in. Or, since you are using phpmyadmin (and as such: PHP), you can pass in a count of the parameters (using PHP's `count()` if they start in an array, for example), and skip the subquery.

You can then join this list outwards to get any further information.